# Fragments And Configuration Change

Tags: java, android, fragment

I'm trying to understand the behavior of fragments when a configuration change occurs.
I have created a project where an activity will host a fragment in `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(savedInstanceState==null) {
        mFragment1 = new Fragment1();
        mManager = getFragmentManager();
        mManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container_1, mFragment1, null)
                .add(R.id.container_1, mFragment1, null)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

If the transaction happens only if savedInstanceState is null, and activity and fragments are destroyed and recreated,why does my activity host the fragment again when the device is rotated?
My point is: if the savedinstancestate is not null after rotation , why does the fragment manager add the fragments again?

Thank you.

Comment: Fragments has it’s own life cycle but it always be embedded with an activity so that the fragments life cycle is directly affected by the host activity’s life cycle

Comment: If you are not saving anything `onSaveInstance` callback, then the savedInstance will be null, hence the fragment transaction occurs again.

Comment: For example: orientation change is a configuration change that triggers this lifecycle. Based on that: That depends on whether you use `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your manifest. If you do, everything will remain the same and views just re-layout themselves. If not, activities and fragments will be recreated with their saved instances, which you can override as `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)`.

Comment: My point is: if the savedinstancestate is not null after rotation , why does the fragment manager add the fragments again?

Answer (score 0):

Fragments has it’s own life cycle but it always be embedded with an activity so that the fragments life cycle is directly affected by the host activity’s life cycle.

I think this will help: When you rotate your device and the screen changes orientation, Android usually destroys your application's existing Activities and Fragments and recreates them. Android does this so that your application can reload resources based on the new configuration.

if you use SaveInstanceState like below, then its hold the value, and will not be null and you can handle.

```
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString(savedName, name);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive what you are looking for is here
https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html
and

if you want to know the shorcut just put

setretaininstance(true);

inside of Fragments.